# How to transfer to a specific storyboard if a condition is true?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm developing a simple quizzes app.

I have a storyboard with textview(contains a question)and 3 buttons (answers) 
when the user presses an answer I need to check if the answer correct or not. if it is correct another storyboard (contain a successful message) will be present.
so I made an action for each button but the problem is that the second storyboard(successful message ) appears only a few seconds and then the previews storyboard(question ) appears again .. I want the successful message to be in the screen 
here is the code:

```
  @IBAction func click1(_ sender: Any) {
    if (opt1.titleLabel?.text) != nil {
        let userAnswer=opt1.titleLabel?.text;

        if ((userAnswer!.elementsEqual(self.optionsArray[0])) == true)
        {
           playSound(fileName: "kidsCheering")

            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let QMessagesViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QMessage") as! QMessagesViewController
            self.present(QMessagesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Thank you

and here is the error that i got : Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: The error will be shown when we have already presented a viewcontroller and try to present another one on same context. Make sure you are trying to present one viewcontroller at a time.

Comment: how? how can i solve this ?

Comment: check if there exist any viewcontroller in `self.presentedViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your viewcontroller variable name like this and remove segue if added or use only use segue:

```
    let qMessagesVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QMessage") as! QMessagesViewController
    self.present(qMessagesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: duplicating what said in other answers isn't a right action , plus naming the vc to small wasnt the answer

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Thank you but actually i am updating my answer then your answer is added thats why seems to duplicate otherwise this is not. Hope you understand

Comment: no you deleted with changing name answer, updated with segue remove then re-add isn't it ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan: if you think that you right then i can delete my answer